# how can i resize font of div by resizing the div using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Hello every one can any one help me out please?
by using this code my font size is go beyound the size of parent div

here

```
$(divid).resizable({
            maxHeight: parseInt(200),
            maxWidth: parseInt(180),
            resize: function(event, ui) {

                var width1 = parseInt(ui.element.css('width'));
                var height1 = parseInt(ui.element.css('height'));

                ui.element.css({'font-size': width1+'px'});
                ui.element.css({'line-height': height1+'px'});
            }
});
```

where 'divid' is parent div where child div is present to fire resizing event of font, but i don't want font size go beyond the parent div, text is also not hidden..

can you please help me out???

Answer (score 1):

Simply try dividing `width1` and `height1` by `10`. Of course there are more sophisticated things you could try, but this seems to work pretty well. I whipped up a little demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/6FTdK/).

```
$(divid).resizable({
    maxHeight: parseInt(200),
    maxWidth: parseInt(180),
    resize: function(evt, ui) {        
        var width1 = parseInt(ui.element.css('width')),
            height1 = parseInt(ui.element.css('height'));
        ui.element.css({
            'font-size': (width1/10)+'px',
            'line-height': (height1/10)+'px'
        });
    }
});
```

(Also note that you can combine the `ui.element.css` calls into one call by passing an object.)